# @PreAuthorize stops propagating exceptions thrown during evaluation of security checks

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, aop

I have a controller with several endpoints. Every endpoint is mapped to a service which could return 200 or throw an exception, that is then handled and will return the correct error message.

For example, if a user is not found I throw a `UserNotFoundException`, which is then caught in the *ControllerAdvisor* that maps it in a 404 not found.

Everything worked fine, until I added the @PreAuthorize. It looks like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("@userController.userService.getUser(#userId).username == authentication.principal.name")
```

The problem is that if `getUser` throws an exception I get a 500 in place of a 404.

The stack trace looks like this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '@userController.userService.getUser(#userId).username == authentication.principal.name'
>
> at ...
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.ExpressionInvocationTargetException: A problem occurred when trying to execute method 'getUser' on object of type ...
>
> at ...
>
> Caused by: UserNotFoundException

So it looks like the problem is caused by the `UserNotFoundException`, which is not properly re-thrown by the `PreAuthorize` implementation.

This looks like a typical scenario, but I've researched a lot and I didn't find any solution. How can I get my 404 when a user is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no added benefit of using `@PreAuthorize` in this case.

Just throw your `UserNotFoundException` within your business logic and map this exception to a `404` in your `ControllerAdvisor` like you did before.

Comment: Ok I may and there isn't any technical problem with it, but isn't mixing business logic and aspect logic against the AOP principle?

Comment: `@PreAuthorize` is here to return `403` if a user is not authorized to invoke a certain endpoint, but you want a `404` in this case. I would consider that good practice if you are doing REST, because you don't want to expose the existence of a forbidden resource. So I would argue that it's ok in your case.

Comment: So an endpoint secured with a JWT isn't REST?

Comment: No, JWT + REST is perfectly fine. Authenticating an endpoint (with JWT in your case obviously) has nothing to do with whether that endpoint is RESTful or not.

Comment: Ok I doubted it because you said "if you are doing REST", anyway thank you for the explanation